# Error 404 when trying to access my rest api from post for a jakarta EE project on payara server. Not used javaEE in a very long time

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, payara

Here is my persistence.xml for an embedded h2 database defining the database
properties

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="com.apps.io_user_management_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" 
transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
      <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:target/h2-2" />
      <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
      <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My web.xml describing the servlet mappings for the rest api

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
         <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
        <servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
              <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet- 
              class>
              <init-param>
              <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
              <param-value>com.apps.io.webservice.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
              </init-param>
              <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
    
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/rest/api/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
      </web-app>
```

My Entity class for the User class for CRUD

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user")
    public class User {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private long userId;
    
        @Column
        private String firstName;
    
        @Column
        private String lastName;
    
        @Column
        private String email;
    
        @Column
        private String birthday;
    
        @Column
        private String password;

        public long getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(long userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getBirthday() {
            return birthday;
        }

        public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
            this.birthday = birthday;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    
    }
```

My CDI Service to perform the necessary crud functions.

```
    @ApplicationScoped
    @Transactional
    public class UserService {
    
        private final EntityManagerFactory emf = 
        Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.apps.io_user_management_war_1.0- 
        SNAPSHOTPU");
        private final EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    
        public List<User> getAllUsers() {
            return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM user c", 
        User.class).getResultList();
        }
    
        public User createUser(User user) {
            entityManager.persist(user);
            return user;
        }
    
        public User getUser(String email) {
            TypedQuery<User> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM user e 
            WHERE e.email = :email", User.class);
            query.setParameter("email", email);
            return query.getSingleResult();
        }
    
        public User updateUser(User user) {
            entityManager.merge(user);
            return user;
        }
    
    }
```

My Application Sub Class for the rest api service

```
    @ApplicationPath("rest")
    public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

        @Override
        public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
            Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
            addRestResourceClasses(resources);
            return resources;
        }

        /**
         * Do not modify addRestResourceClasses() method.
         * It is automatically populated with
         * all resources defined in the project.
         * If required, comment out calling this method in getClasses().
         */
        private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        }
    
    }
```

The Rest Api class containg all the rest api endpoints.

```
    @Path("api")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public class ApiResource {

        /**
         * Creates a new instance of ApiResource
         */
         public ApiResource() {
         }

         @Inject
         private UserService userService;
    
         @GET
         @Path("/getAllUsers")
         public List<User> getAllUsers() {
             return userService.getAllUsers();
         }
    
         @POST`enter code here`
         @Path("/createUser")
         public User createUser(User user) {
            return userService.createUser(user);
         }
    
        @POST
        @Path("/updateUser")
        public User updateUser(User user) {
            return userService.updateUser(user);
        }
    
        @GET
        @Path("/getUser")
        public User getUser(@QueryParam("email") String email) {
            return userService.getUser(email);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 404 is Resource Not Found

Comment: Normally, if the problem was just about POST, you'd expect it to return 405

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out, I have a very similar problem